# Bound of the difference between two converging infinite series

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Let $f(x)$, and $g(x)$ be two functions given by the infinite series :

$$f(x)=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}f_{k}(x)$$
$$g(x)=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}g_{k}(x)$$
And let the regions of convergence of both series be the same. Furthermore, suppose that : 
$$\lim_{N\rightarrow \infty}(f_{N}(x)-g_{N}(x))=0$$
is there a good way to find the bound : 
$$\left | f(x)-g(x) \right |<a$$

Comment: Wouldn't $a$ be $x$-dependent in general, e.g. if we set $f_k=g_k+x\delta_{k0}$?

Comment: Is the domain for $x$ bounded? Are there any assumptions on the $f_k$ and $g_k$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, the desired boundedness does not need to hold, as can be seen using a simple counterexample:

Even for bounded domain $\Omega$, we can choose $f_k(x) = g_k(x)$ for all $k\ge 1$. All assumptions are fulfilled then. Now pick $f_0(x)$ bounded for $x\in\Omega$ and $g_0(x)$ unbounded on $\Omega$. Then $|f(x)-g(x)| = |f_0(x) - g_0(x)|$ is unbounded on $\Omega$.

If we can additionally assume continuity and uniform boundedness of all $f_k, g_k$ on $\Omega$, and uniform convergence of the sums, then the limit functions are bounded on $\Omega$, and so is their difference.

Answer (score 3):

**Remark**

You do not need the hypothesis

$$\lim_{N\to+\infty}f_N (x)-g_N (x)=0$$
since
$$\lim_{+\infty}f_N (x)=\lim_{+\infty}g_N (x)=0$$
because the series $$\sum f_k (x) $$ is convergent.

Comment: Why this downvote. if the series $\sum u_n $ converges, the general term goes to zero.

Comment: I did not downvote, but a reason may be that what you've written is not an answer, but rather a comment.

Comment: People downvote for reasons that may seem strange. Often it is because the down voter doesn't understand what's going on.

Comment: @MathematicsStudent1122 I view it as an answer because it shows there is really no hypothesis at all beyond the two series converging in a common domain. Once you know that, counterexamples are trivial, for example $\sum x^n$ and $0+0+0+\cdots$ on $(0,1).$ Perhaps Salahamam_ Fatima could point this out at the end of his answer.